# Embedding Java Applet into .html file

Tags: java, html, applet

I am having trouble embedding my applet into a webpage. I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

*** I have my html file in the same directory as my .class files

My main method is in CardApp class

This is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>TestJCardBet.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet codebase="" code="CardApp.class" height="400" width="500"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, please use google before posting questions like this.

Comment: I did use google, that's how I came up with this code.

Comment: You say *"My main method is in CardApp class"* but applets don't need a main method (at least not a `public static void main(String s[])`). Having one may make it easier to test the applet as a stand alone application but the browser will not invoke it.

Comment: Post your applet's source code.

Comment: Besides posting the source code (or better an SSCCE - http://pscode.org/sscce.html), make sure the console is open, and copy/paste any output (errors & exceptions).

Comment: I do use Google, that's how I came to this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Making applets work across a wide range of browsers is surprisingly hard.  The tags weren't properly standardized in the early days, so Internet Explorer and Mozilla went separate directions.

Sun developed a generic JavaScript to handle all the specific browser quirks, so that you don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Add this to your `<head>` section:

```
<script src="//www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
```

And this to `<body>` section:

```
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase: 'http://my.url/my/path/to/codebase',
                      code: 'my.main.Applet.class',
                      archive: 'my-archive.jar',
                      width: '800', 
                      height: '600'};
    var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
    var version = '1.5'; // JDK version
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

See [Java™ Rich Internet Applications Deployment Advice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for a detailed explanation of the script and all the possible options.

Comment: is code base the directory where I have my .class files? I have the .html file in the same directory as the .class files. What should I put for codebase?

Comment: Also is archive a required attribute? I don't have a jar. Should I build one? or would it work without it?

Comment: Also, the line var parameters. do I just leave it like that? or do I need to substitute java_arguments for my main arguments? Actually my program doesn't require any arguments to run it.

Comment: the jdk version, is that my version on my computer? or the compliance version I used to build my project?

Comment: codebase is the URL where either your jar file or individual class files are located.  If you use a jar file, then you must use the archive property.  Otherwise, omit the archive property.  The JDK version is whatever version your code depends upon.  So if you're developing with JDK 1.5, then specify 1.6.  If you're coding with JDK 1.6, then specify 1.6.

Comment: If you aren't using a web server and your class files or .jar archive is placed locally on your machine, make sure you start your codebase URL with file:// instead of http://

Comment: It doesn't work any more on Chrome, as it has no more support for NPAPI plugins. https://www.java.com/it/download/faq/chrome.xml

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `deployJava.js` is preferred approach nowadays.

Then follow several old multi-browser tricks for historical completeness.

https://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/63-How-to-use-Java-applets-in-modern-browsers.html:

```
<object id="testapplet-object" 
        classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        width="256" height="256"
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u30-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,6,0,0">
  <param name="archive" value="mytest.jar" />
  <param name="code" value="my.package.MyClass" />
  <param name="myParam" value="My Param Value" />
  <embed id="testapplet-embed"
         type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
         width="256" height="256" 
         archive="mytest.jar"
         code="my.package.MyClass" 
         pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"
         myParam="My Param Value" />
  </embed>
</object>
```

http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-java.html (has several variations):

```
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
        width="150" height="80">
  <param name="codebase" value="data" >
  <param name="code" value="JitterText">
  <param name="BGCOLOR" value="000000">
  <param name="TEXTCOLOR" value="FF0000">
  <param name="TEXT" value="OJITesting!">
  <param name="SPEED" value="250">
  <param name="RANDOMCOLOR" value="1">

  <!--[if gte IE 7]> <!-->
  <object classid="java:JitterText.class"
          codebase="data"
          type="application/x-java-applet"
          width="150" height="80">
    <param name="code" value="JitterText">
    <!-- Safari browser needs the following param -->
    <param name="JAVA_CODEBASE" value="data">
    <param name="BGCOLOR" value="000000">
    <param name="TEXTCOLOR" value="FF0000">
    <param name="TEXT" value="OJITesting!">
    <param name="SPEED" value="250">
    <param name="RANDOMCOLOR" value="1">
    alt : <a href="data/JitterText.class">JitterText.class</a>
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    alt : <a href="data/JitterText.class">JitterText.class</a>
  <![endif]-->

</object>
```