# Eclipse: Run As -> Java Applet is missing

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am trying to run the following code as a Java Applet in Eclipse:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MyPApplet extends PApplet {

    private String URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG";
    private PImage backgroundImg;

    public void setup() {
        size(1200, 1200);
        backgroundImg = loadImage(URL, "jpg");

    }

    public void draw() {

        backgroundImg.resize(0,  height);
        image(backgroundImg, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

However, when I select Run -> Run As it displays "(none applicable)". I literally copied and pasted the code straight from the instructor's notes, and then the instructions say select Run -> Run As -> Java Applet. That option is not there.

I tried going into Run Configurations and add a new Java Applet, however, it asks for an Applet name, which I tried putting java.applet.Applet to no avail. My friend has his running just fine with the exact same code.

EDIT: Restarted Eclipse, Now there is an error saying MyPApplet cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet; however, MyPApplet extends PApplet which extends java.applet.Applet....

Help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run applet in eclipse using web project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792642/how-to-run-applet-in-eclipse-using-web-project)

Comment: @Syd try switching perspective or workspace or even restart eclipse

Comment: @TheProgrammerG, I restarted. Now when I try to run it, it says that MyPApplet cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet... But MyPApplet extends PApplet, which extends java.applet.Applet....

Comment: @Syd what step is it stuck on? (post your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys. It couldn't run as an applet because I was using a newer version of the `processing` library (ie `processing 3.0.1`) and the instructor's code was made using `processing 2.2.1`. Turns out that they changed it so that `PApplet` no longer extends `java.applet.Applet`, so it couldn't be run. I had to either use the older library or use a new function from the new library.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Processing 3 with Eclipse. 
Add PApplet.main with "package.ClassName" as an argument in your main function and run as java application.

```
package ptest;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PVector;
public class MyApp extends PApplet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("ptest.MyApp");
}
private Segment a;
public void setup() {

}
public void settings() {
    size(800, 800);
}
public void draw() {
    background(0);
    line(0,0,100,100);
}
}
```