# Uploading a Java Program in a browser

Tags: java, web-applications, browser, executable-jar

I have created two "mini-games" in Java. I'd like to upload it to a website but I don't know how. The games a executable jar files at the moment. I can run them from the desktop by double clicking on the icon, but I don't know how to upload them into a website or make a link that automatically downloads the program in another computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272666/embedding-java-applet-into-html-file

Comment: @durbnpoisn, My vote is, too broad for StackOverflow.  My take is that CoderOgden is asking how to publish his work on the web.  "I'd like to upload it to a website but I don't know how."

Comment: Look into [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/).