# How to execute a jar file on button click from html page

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, jar

I want to execute a jar file after getting some input from the web page on button click. I tried php exec method , but it runs the jar file at the time of loading the php page (even before button click).

```
        <input type="button" title="Generate the summary" name="sum" value="Summarize" id="summarize" onclick="summarize()">
    <script>
        function summarize()
        {
            <?php exec("java -jar summarizer_1.jar ",$output); ?>
            <?php echo $output;?>
        } 
    </script>
```

some people suggested me AJAX but I think its increasing complications in the code. Can there be a simple solution to this problem?

P.S. I used php only to make the .jar call, php is nowhere useful for me in the code.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and javascript. Your PHP functions won't work in JS.

Comment: it works. you can mix php and JS. i do it all the time. Though it is not good practice.

Comment: Can there be any other way to do this? Any web technology would work for me, as I'm using both js/php to call the .jar

Comment: What error do you get? via your console(F12) or your network tab in your browser??

Comment: @PhpDev What I meant was the PHP is processed on server side so obviously `exec` would execute there itself.

Comment: there no error in the code , its just that I want the execution of jar on button click but its executing immediately after the page is loaded (even if u do nothing at all)

Comment: I know php would execute first, my attempt makes no sense, so only I'm asking for some solution

Comment: Where is the `jar` located? On the server?

Comment: Yes, the jar is on server side

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272666/embedding-java-applet-into-html-file

Comment: Make sure you the file path of the .jar is correct

Comment: The path is correct because I am getting the output even before I want.

Comment: Tried the link @abhishekkannojia .. Its not really relevant to my question

Comment: where does the variable $output come from in the first line of the function summarize?

Comment: it's always better for you to do something like that using ajax to connect to your php server which is executes your command line using `exec`

Comment: Thanks guys.. AJAX worked.

Comment: I created a new file called execute.php in which the exec call to .jar was mentioned. `code` <input type="button" title="Generate the summary" name="sum" value="Summarize" id="summarize" onclick="summarize()">
  <script>
   function summarize() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "execute.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
} 
  </script>